# Compiling two Fortran programs using Eclipse, duplicate symbol `_main`

Tags: eclipse, fortran, photran

I am newbie in Fortran in eclipse. I am trying to create many Fortran source files inside one Fortran source folder (see pic1, ex1.fo8 and ex2.fo8 are my source files in the source folder 'tut'). When I am compiling ex2.f08, I am getting error as shown in pic2.

How to resolve this without making a separate project for each source file?

[image]

Comment: If you want people to read your code, and you should want people to read your code, post it.  Post the code, not links to pictures of the code.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your comment on the issue. But at this point I am not concern on my code. My concern is integrating many examples like ex1.f08 and ex2.f08 in one package rather then making separate Fortran  package for each source file.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse programs at all for such simple programs. Just compile it on the command line. You will save loads of time.